# What is the meaning of add X-Request-Guid header

Tags: http, header

I notice that the request to stackoverflow.com will get a response with X-Request-Guid header.

So what X-Request-Guid for?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, it's unique request id generated for each and every request to come at the server.